# how to use corbel and calibri font in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4.2

i need to use corbel and caliber font in textview , textfield and label in my new application. I have searched for it in google but i did not got any solutions . Can any one please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1) Add desired fonts to Xcode as resource.

2) Open **info.plist** file. Now create a key called **UIAppFonts** and make it an array. Add the filename of the font as a value.

```
   <key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>corbel.ttf</string>
</array>
```

3) Save **info.plist** FILE.

4) To use the font in your application add this line.

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"corbel" size:32.0]
```

**Courtesy :**

[**Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)

[**CUSTOM FONTS IN IOS.**](http://kgriff.posterous.com/45359635)

**P.S.**  But to determine the exact name of font put temporary line of code as even small case sensitivity might cause a problem loading fonts.

```
  NSLog(@"%@",[UIFont familyNames]);
```

This will print names of all the fonts on the device. Find the one that matches your font.Whatever the font name you get use it in the line in **Step 4**.

Courtesy: [**How do I include a font with my iPhone application?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566054/how-do-i-include-a-font-with-my-iphone-application)

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom fonts to Xcode, I think [this](http://www.perfectline.ee/blog/uiappfonts-custom-fonts-with-the-iphoneipad-3-2-sdk) article can help you out doing so. I also found [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSuSDuoyfh4) video. As for the caliber and corbel files, a quick search in google will get what you want: **corbel caliber tff**.

Answer (score 1):

Install same font in Mac OSX and try to find same font name in textedit application.

type exact spelling (with case sensitivity) in Xcode.

some time it happens font file name is different and we type it differently.
put the exect file name in plist file... but use the installed font name in application (Xcode.)