# how to use custom font in html pages for UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, fonts

I am having the "Futura.ttf" font file.
I am displaying a HTML page in the UIWebView, but my requirement is that i want to use the custom font in my css file.

so is there any way that i can use the custom font in my css file ???

All suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to load custom fonts into your UIWebView in iOS3.2 and above. Add the font to your bundle (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application/2616101#2616101)) then just reference the font in your UIWebView's stylesheet like you would any other font:

```
<style type='text/css'>font { font-family: DroidSerif; } </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have [Cufon](http://wiki.github.com/sorccu/cufon/about) and [sIFR](http://novemberborn.net/sifr3) as your options.

Typeface.js is a pure JavaScript Replacement
Cufon is a pure JavaScript Replacement
sIFR is Flash and Java font implementation,
FLIR JavaScript and PHP implementation

Some Comparisons

- http://thatguynamedandy.com/blog/text-replacement-comparison
- http://thinkclay.com/technology/cufon-sifr-flir
- [[http://aaronwinborn.com/blogs/aaron/cufón-alternative-sifr-image-replacement](http://aaronwinborn.com/blogs/aaron/cuf%C3%B3n-alternative-sifr-image-replacement)](http://aaronwinborn.com/blogs/aaron/cuf%C3%B3n-alternative-sifr-image-replacement)

Below is taken from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692990/sifr-vs-cufon-vs-typeface-js/692994#692994) Worth reading the whole thread, has greatdetails.

**Typeface.js**

Advantages:

- User doesn’t have to have Flash
  plugin installed on their browser
- Easier to create with just a few
  lines of Javascript
- For page loading it just needs to
  load the Javascript

Disadvantages:

- Text is not selectable because it
  outputs it like an image. I looked at
  some examples, right clicked on a
  word and had to view as an image.
  Every single word had this behaviour.
  Big thumbs down.
- Usage for body copy will slow down
  loading time, so it is recommended to
  use only for headlines.
- Cannot be read by screen readers
- Visual looks blurry
- Not all browser compliant and still
  has a lot of development left to be
  done

**sIFR**

Advantages:

- Can be read by screen readers as a
  normal headline because it is a
  behaviour layer on top of the markup
  and styling.
- Text is selectable
- SEO friendly
- Displays text as is like any other
  web font. Crisp and not blurry!
- Has addons like jQuery sIFR Plugin!

Disadvantages:

- Requires Javascript to be enabled
- Flash plugin must be installed in the
  browser
- Need Adobe Flash Studio to create it
  BUT there is a pretty nifty sIFR
  generator that creates the file for
  you!
- For page loading, it has to request
  for Flash, Javascript and CSS files
  attached to it, which can potentially
  get bogged down if you are using sIFR
  in too many places.
- Cannot display on an iPhone. Yet…

**Cufón** (similar to Typeface.js)

Enter Cufón, the Javascript-based font replacement solution which makes heavy use of canvas and VML. This offers a great alternative to other solutions out there - no Flash or images required.

There are some issues with using Cufón on a live site, the most notable being the inability to highlight and copy/paste text, which is really the biggest issue for your site's users.

Combine that with the EULA issues, which prevent you from being able to legally embed fonts in Javascript files for most fonts on the market today.

The other issue is knowing what fonts can be used with Cufón. For sIFR, most fonts are fair game, since the font is embedded in a Flash movie, which is typically an approved usage by most font foundries for most fonts. With Cufón, the Javascript files used for the font can be easily "stolen" and either used on another website or reverse engineered.

Comment: Great :) Cufon is what i use as well, it's my current preference.

Comment: This answer is no longer your only option. See my answer below.