# UILabel reduce character spacing

Tags: ios6, uikit, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I need a way to reduce character spacing by 50% or just bi a number of points. I checked online and found that it might be doable with the NSAttributedString by seting its kerning to a negative number. Can anyone tell me how or give me a different way to do this?

Comment: have u found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6785429/1305001 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/13586537/1305001

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13586537/1305001