# Objective C - UITextView letter spacing and vertical spacing

Tags: objective-c

How can I set the letter spacing and vertical spacing for a UITextView?
Trying to do it from nib if possible but if not, is there a property I can set through code?

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no property within the [UITextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html) to explicitly set the letter spacing, or vertical spacing - with the native controls it can't be done.

If you want to do this you're going to have to roll your own. There's a [SO thread about changing the UILabel/UIFont letter spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544905/how-to-change-an-uilabel-uifonts-letter-spacing) which ought to provide you with a direction to go in.

With that said, I have to ask the question why you want to do this? Apple is **very** specific about it's interface elements, and my thought is that tweaking a UITextView is going to be very off putting to your users.

Answer (score 1):

As gavin has said, really;  if possible you could change to a UILabel and set the lineBreakMode property, in conjunction with the contentSize property of the label's frame to partly achieve some light modification.

You could also replace spaces with a number of spaces for example from a string object, but again as has been said, I wouldn't advise tampering too far with this, especially if its going to be a public appstore project.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are looking for line height you can get like this.

```
yourUITextView.font.lineHeight
```

This would give you line height according to the current font size. This works perfectly in iOS 8. Not sure about backward compatibility.