# How to set kerning in iPhone UILabel

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel, kerning

I am developing an iPhone app, and I want to set kerning in UILabel. The code I've written (possibly around `kCTKernAttributeName`) seems to be in error. How might I approach fixing this?

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attStr;   
NSString *str = @"aaaaaaa";    
CFStringRef kern = kCTKernAttributeName;        
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2.0f];    
NSDictionary *attributesDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:num 
forKey:(NSString*)kern];        
[attStr initWithString:str attributes:attributesDict];      
CGRect frame1 = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40);    
UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame1];    
label1.text = attStr    
[self.view addSubview:label1];
```

Comment: Could you explain what kerning means?

Comment: kerning means a space between characters

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46517511/1223728) answer to calculate kerning to fit label's width.

Comment: **it's important to note 2023 that Apple now have actual TRACKING, not just KERNing**

Answer (score 61):

Old question, but you can do it now (easily).

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString;
attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Please get wider"];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName value:@5 range:NSMakeRange(10, 5)];
[self.label setAttributedText:attributedString];
```

[image]

For Nov 2013, Just to expand on this great answer, here's some totally typical code. Usually you'd set the font as well.  Note in the comments the old-fashioned way using ordinary old .text.  Hope it helps someone

```
NSString *yourText = @"whatever";

UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)];

// simple approach with no tracking...
// label.text = yourText;
// [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:24]];

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString;

attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourText];

[attributedString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName
                         value:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0]
                         range:NSMakeRange(0, [yourText length])];

[attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                         value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:24]
                         range:NSMakeRange(0, [yourText length])];

label.attributedText = attributedString;

label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

[label sizeToFit];
```

Comment: This is not kerning. This is tracking.

Comment: Apple specifically uses 'Kern' to describe this letter spacing behavior. Is Apple's internal API really setting tracking instead of kerning? Maybe. Regardless, it seemed like this would provide a good solution for people looking for this type of text formatting.

Comment: Sure. But evenly increasing the space is letter-spacing or tracking. Kerning is letter-pair specific. Apple are using the wrong terminology.

Comment: Since attributed strings handle formatting on a character-by-character basis instead of a string basis, technically it is in fact kerning.

Comment: Please note this solution is only applicable in iOS 6+

Comment: This code is in fact doing specific letter pairs -- note how you supply a range.  It is setting them all to the same value (ie "5").

Comment: And furthermore, "ledding" is pronounced "ledding" (just as in "Led Zepplin.")  It comes from the metallic substance, Pb, led.  It drives me nuts when people pronounce that word the wrong way!!  :)

Comment: @Undistraction - they FINALLY added tracking (not kerning) for google ... **it's important to note 2023 that Apple now have actual TRACKING, not just KERNing**

Answer (score 25):

### Before:

[image: before]

### After:

[image: cafter]

Here's a Swift 3 extension that let's you set a UILabel's kerning via **code** or **storyboard**:

```
extension UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var kerning: Float {
        get {
            var range = NSMakeRange(0, (text ?? "").count)
            guard let kern = attributedText?.attribute(NSAttributedStringKey.kern, at: 0, effectiveRange: &range),
                let value = kern as? NSNumber
                else {
                    return 0
            }
            return value.floatValue
        }
        set {
            var attText:NSMutableAttributedString

            if let attributedText = attributedText {
                attText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedText)
            } else if let text = text {
                attText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
            } else {
                attText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
            }

            let range = NSMakeRange(0, attText.length)
            attText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.kern, value: NSNumber(value: newValue), range: range)
            self.attributedText = attText
        }
    }
}
```

### Demo usage:

```
myLabel.kerning = 3.0
```

or

[image]

The demo uses 3.0 kerning for drama, but I've found **0.1 - 0.8** tends to work well in practice.

Comment: Perfect! That's the only extension that works without any warning for me. Do you know some extension that'll do the same for LineHeight?

Comment: If you set the kerning in a storyboard, and then change the label text in code, the kerning is not applied to the new text. You can re-apply the kerning in code and that will make it work, or you could perhaps subclass UILabel and override setText to re-apply kerning if it's set.

Comment: NICE! Your a champ ;)

Answer (score 19):

Taking DBD's answer, I made a category on UILabel which allows setting the kerning if running on iOS6+ with graceful fall back to just setting text on previous iOS versions.  Might be of help to others...

**UILabel+TextKerning.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UILabel (TextKerning)

/**
 * Set the label's text to the given string, using the given kerning value if able.
 * (i.e., if running on iOS 6.0+). The kerning value specifies the number of points
 * by which to adjust spacing between characters (positive values increase spacing,
 * negative values decrease spacing, a value of 0 is default)
 **/
- (void) setText:(NSString *)text withKerning:(CGFloat)kerning;

/**
 * Set the kerning value of the currently-set text.  The kerning value specifies the number of points
 * by which to adjust spacing between characters (positive values increase spacing,
 * negative values decrease spacing, a value of 0 is default)
 **/
- (void) setKerning:(CGFloat)kerning;

@end
```

**UILabel+TextKerning.m**

```
#import "UILabel+TextKerning.h"

@implementation UILabel (TextKerning)

-(void) setText:(NSString *)text withKerning:(CGFloat)kerning
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setAttributedText:)])
    {
        NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];
        [attributedString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName
                                 value:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:kerning]
                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])];
        [self setAttributedText:attributedString];
    }
    else
        [self setText:text];
}

-(void) setKerning:(CGFloat)kerning
{
    [self setText:self.text withKerning:kerning];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just to be up-to-date here, iOS 6 introduced attributedText for `UILabel` and `UITextView`!

UILabel reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/attributedText

Answer (score 5):

Just do this in Swift:

```
    let myTitle = "my title"
    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    let attributes: NSDictionary = [
        NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 20),
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor(),
        NSKernAttributeName:CGFloat(2.0)
    ]
    let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: myTitle, attributes: attributes as? [String : AnyObject])

    titleLabel.attributedText = attributedTitle
    titleLabel.sizeToFit()
```

Comment: This is the only answer that doesn't require you to know the length of the string beforehand. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

An example using IBDesignables and IBInspectables where you can manage to set the kerning value through storyboard only.
I found it very practical and I thought to share it with you.

**UILabelKerning.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE

@interface UILabelKerning : UILabel
@property (assign, nonatomic) IBInspectable int kerning;
@end
```

**UILabelKerning.m**

```
#import "UILabelKerning.h"

@implementation UILabelKerning


-(void)awakeFromNib {

    [self setTheAttributes];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
    {
        // Initialization code
    }

    return self;
}
-(void)setTheAttributes{
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString =[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:self.attributedText];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName
                             value:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.kerning]
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [self.text length])];
    [self setAttributedText:attributedString];
}
@end
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Attention please! I adopt this solution but unfortunately my app was rejected because "kerning" is a property name used in private api.

Comment: @christianmini Sorry to hear that! What private api?

Comment: this is the message:Performance - 2.5.1

Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs:

kerning.

The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change............So I think the problem is only in the name of the property

Comment: If you are going to try with the property name changed and if it is accepted at App Store please let me know so I will change it here also :)

Comment: @ Arben Pnishi Certainly

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, `UILabel` will not render the characteristics of `NSAttributedString`. There are a couple of nice open source solutions. I recently used [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) as a swap in replacement for UILabel that accepts NSAttributedString.

[DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) (former NSAttributedString+HTML) is also getting a bit of buzz lately.

Comment: thanks comment. I knew Core Text String Attributes refer to  kCTKernAttributeName instead of NSAttributedString. So, I checked this code. then I found the error sentence "[attStr initWithString:str attributes:attributesDict]". just a bit more, I would like to try to fix this code.

Comment: Make sure that you're linking to the CoreText framework as well as importing the CoreText header. In saying that, UILabel will not do what you're looking to do. Much easier to use on the replacements I mentioned.

Comment: too late re-comment. I understood your comment. I am going to set by HTML.thank you very much!

Comment: Actually label has an **attributedText** property.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4 and 5**

```
extension NSAttributedString {

    /// Returns a new instance of NSAttributedString with same contents and attributes with kerning added.
    /// - Parameter kerning: a kerning you want to assign to the text.
    /// - Returns: a new instance of NSAttributedString with given kerning.
    func withKerning(_ kerning: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)
        attributedString.addAttributes([.kern: kerning],
                                       range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.count))
        return NSAttributedString(attributedString: attributedString)
    }
 ]
```

Answer (score -1):

In Swift 2.0...

Add an extension:

```
extension UIView {
    func attributes(font: String, color: UIColor, fontSize: CGFloat, kern: Double) -> [String: NSObject] {
        let attribute = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color,
            NSKernAttributeName: kern,
            NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: font, size: fontSize)!
        ]
        return attribute
    }
}
```

Now, just set your UILabel as attributedText:

```
self.label.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "SwiftExample", attributes: attributes("SourceSans-Regular", color: UIColor.whiteColor(), fontSize: 20, kern: 2.0))
```

Obviously, I added a bunch of parameters that you may not need. Play around -- feel free to rewrite the method -- I was looking for this on a bunch of different answers so figured I'd post the whole extension in case it helps someone out there...  -rab