# iOS 7 Applying kerning and line spacing to text

Tags: iphone, text, ios7, kerning

I have the following code which works flawlessly in iOS 6, problem is it has no effect whatsoever in iOS 7. 
How do I apply kerning and line spacing in iOS 7?

```
+ (NSAttributedString *)attributedText:(NSString *)text inFont:(UIFont *)font {
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
    style.lineSpacing = 5;
    CGFloat kernSize = -0.6;
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:style range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName value:@(kernSize) range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)];

    return attributedString;
}
```

Comment: How do you know it has no effect? Are you taking the return value and assigning it to a UILabel to actually see the result? How are you creating your UILabel and what are its properties?

Comment: I'm using code nearly identical to what you posted, and getting kerning and spacing fine in iOS 7.  Your issue is not in the code you posted.

Comment: If anyone needs a solution, check it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35156265/4173671

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a duplicate to [Why Does Kerning fail for NSAttributedString in IOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253442/why-does-kerning-fail-for-nsattributedstring-in-ios7/)

For some strange reason it does not work with the font Courier (in iOS7!) but with CourierNewPSMT.

Maybe try with different fonts.... here is a nice list of fonts on the iphone: http://iosfonts.com/