# Why Does Kerning fail for NSAttributedString in IOS7

Tags: ios7

My app has a UILabel formatted as an NSAttributedString with
the attribute:    'NSKernAttributeName @1.9,'

1. When the below code is compiled on iPad running IOS6, the kern works as expected.
2. When compiled on iPad running IOS7, no kerning occurs.

I have filed Bug at Apple Developer site.  #15108371 - No Response yet

```
NSString *formattedNumber;
NSNumber *scoreNum = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithLongLong:thisScore];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterPadBeforeSuffix;
formatter.formatWidth = 10;
formatter.paddingCharacter = @"0";
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = NO;
formattedNumber = [formatter stringFromNumber:scoreNum];

//Creat atributed string of formated number.
NSShadow *textShadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
textShadow.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.7 blue:1 alpha:1.0];
textShadow.shadowBlurRadius = 5.0;
textShadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,0);

NSAttributedString  *pHighScoreStyle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:formattedNumber attributes: @{
             NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"courier" size:16],
  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.6 green:0.8 blue:1.0 alpha:0.8],
             NSKernAttributeName: @1.9,
            NSShadowAttributeName: textShadow    }   ];

//Change the disply value.
runningScore.attributedText = pHighScoreStyle;
```

Comment: I have the same problem with Kerning working in iOS6 and not working in iOS7. I do not use the UILabel like you but the low level CoreText. Have you heard back from Apple? Did they accept your bug?

Comment: Nothing from Apple, yet.

Comment: If anyone needs a solution, check it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580736/how-to-increase-the-character-spacing-in-uilabel/35156300#35156300

Answer (score 2):

OK. I had the same problem (see comment above). It depends on the font (I used Courier as well). For some strange reason Courier does not support kerning (in iOS7!). **Use CourierNewPSMT and everything works as expected** .... at least for me.

BTW: Here is a nice list of fonts on the iphone:
http://iosfonts.com/

Comment: Thank you, naeger.  Thanks for the font list, too.   Hard days for apple.

Comment: Yes, I switched to New Courier and found kerning to work as expected.  Begs the question regarding Font Standards.  Does New Courier meet a more sophisticated standard?

Comment: No, I think thats just a bug with Apple