# Swift different alignment (or dynamic spacing) inside same label text

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, string, uilabel

Was wondering if there is a way to set a dynamic space between words inside a `UILabel` to obtain something like this

```
|                                                               |
|WordA         -dynamic_space_to_fill_the_label-           WordB|
|                                                               |
```

Where the `|` represent the borders of my `UILabel`.
It would be like I had left alignment for `WordA` and right alignment for `WordB`.

Any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580736/how-to-increase-the-character-spacing-in-uilabel

Comment: That is for creating space between letters of a text, I am looking for something to separate words and put them at the extremes of a `UILabel` as if I was using different alignments for `WordA & WordB`.