# Get kerning in IOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts

I'm new in IOS.
So my problem is, that I need to get kerning between two glyphs.
First I tried like this:

```
NSString *text = @"AB";
NSDictionary* stringAttrs = @{ NSFontAttributeName : self.level.font,         
NSKernAttributeName:@0.0f };
CGSize size = [text sizeWithAttributes:stringAttrs];

//For better understanding
NSString *textA = @"A";
NSString *textB = @"B";
CGSize sizeA = [text sizeWithAttributes:stringAttrs];
CGSize sizeB = [text sizeWithAttributes:stringAttrs];
double kerning = size.width - sizeA.width - size.widthB;
```

I thought that, for single symbol width would be without advance. But I was wrong. It's did't help me. Than I tried CoreText.

```
CFStringRef str = (__bridge CFStringRef)@"A";
CFIndex count = CFStringGetLength(str);

CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"Lora", 100, NULL);

UniChar *characters = (UniChar *)malloc(sizeof(UniChar) * count);
CGGlyph *glyphs = (CGGlyph *)malloc(sizeof(CGGlyph) * count);

CFStringGetCharacters(str, CFRangeMake(0, count), characters);
CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(font, characters, glyphs, count);

CGSize *sizeCore = malloc(count * sizeof(CGSize));
CGRect *rectCore = malloc(count * sizeof(CGRect));

double adv = CTFontGetAdvancesForGlyphs (font,
                                         kCTFontHorizontalOrientation,
                                         glyphs,
                                         sizeCore,
                                         count);

CGRect rect = CTFontGetBoundingRectsForGlyphs (font,
                                               kCTFontHorizontalOrientation,
                                               glyphs,
                                               rectCore,
                                               count);

double kerning = adv - rect.size.width; (== 0)
```

`adv` gave the same value as `rect.size.width` and even the same like in first try `size.width`

Do you have any gues? Or link were I can find an answer.
Sorry for mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I found kerning not to work with certain fonts in ios 7. See my answer to this question:
[Why Does Kerning fail for NSAttributedString in IOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253442/why-does-kerning-fail-for-nsattributedstring-in-ios7/19694032#19694032)

Maybe it works with different fonts...