# How to decrease the distance between the two lines in a textView to make characters more closer to each other in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

i am writing the texts from top to bottom and from right to left in japanese as i am taking a uitextview there is a gap between two characters , i want tomake it closer to each other plz give any code or idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is no property within the `UITextView` to explicitly set the letter spacing, or vertical spacing - with the native controls it can't be done.

If you want to do this you're going to have to create your own customized control.

Comment: can u plz give me some idea how to make own customised control to full fil my requirement.

Comment: For that you can refer this SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544905/how-to-change-an-uilabel-uifonts-letter-spacing

Answer (score 0):

For that create your Custom `UITextView` or create Custom Font with your requirement...

For More information see [Set line height in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760924/set-line-height-in-uitextview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use attributed strings, as of iOS6. An attributed string can have a paragraph style, a paragraph style can have line spacing:

[NSAttributedString reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) - the paragraph style attribute name is `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName`.

[NSMutableParagraphStyle setLineSpacing reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMutableParagraphStyle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableParagraphStyle/setLineSpacing%3a)

Comment: i have tried with NSParagraphStyleAttributeName. it is working in simulator but not working in device. plz give me some idea to implement it, i have japanese character with top to bottom and having one character in each line.

Comment: i have an option to change the font dynamically when i am dynamically changing the font then that time it is not working.