# How do I set UILabel's letter spacing from Storyboard/Xib?

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I know [there are ways to adjust letter spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20349131/361247) if I have reference to the `UILabel`, but is there a way to do it from Storyboard?

I don't see the option from here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

There is one more option of `Minimum Font Scale` which will reduce based on percentage what you enter. In addition to it, it will reduce only if the text is exceeding the size of the frame of label. `Tighten Letter Spacing` will reduce the space between characters if necessary.

Comment: Hmm, I've used this before, but I actually want to do the opposite of tightening letter spacing.