# set spaces between letters in textview

Tags: android, android-edittext, space

is there a way to set a custom space (in pixels) between letters to an editText? I found only how to set spaces between the lines, but bot between letters on the same row

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063268/is-it-possible-to-alter-the-letter-spacing-kerning-of-a-font-with-cocoa-touch

Comment: this is not an IOS, objective c question, I need to achieve this on android, as you can see in the question's tags.

Comment: sorry, i didn't see that

Answer (score 12):

Using `android:letterSpacing` i was able to add spacing between characters in a textview

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
   android:id="@+id/textViewValue"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:letterSpacing="0.35"
   android:maxLines="1" />
```

**Related methods:**

[setLetterSpacing(float)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLetterSpacing(float))

Comment: This is only available in  API level +21

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this myself today so here are some updates about this problem :

From API 21 you can use XML attribute `android:letterSpacing="2"` or from code `myEditText.setLetterSpacing(2);`

Before API 21, use a TextWatcher with the following code

```
private static final String LETTER_SPACING = " ";

private EditText myEditText;

private String myPreviousText;

...
// Get the views
myEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edt_code);

myEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
...

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    // Nothing here
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // Nothing here
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    String text = s.toString();

    // Only update the EditText when the user modify it -> Otherwise it will be triggered when adding spaces
    if (!text.equals(myPreviousText)) {            
        // Remove spaces
        text = text.replace(" ", "");

        // Add space between each character
        StringBuilder newText = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            if (i == text.length() - 1) {
                // Do not add a space after the last character -> Allow user to delete last character
                newText.append(Character.toUpperCase(text.charAt(text.length() - 1)));
            }
            else {
                newText.append(Character.toUpperCase(text.charAt(i)) + LETTER_SPACING);
            }
        }

        myPreviousText = newText.toString();

        // Update the text with spaces and place the cursor at the end
        myEditText.setText(newText);
        myEditText.setSelection(newText.length());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implament a custom [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html), and add X spaces every time the user enteres 1.

Comment: pardon my candor, but this solution is horrible, works but is horrible.

Comment: I agree, it was an off-the-top-of-my-head response, how would you accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

i have used this, and works for most API levels if not all of them.

> **KerningViews**
>
> Provides a set of views which allows to adjust the spacing between the characters of that view, AKA, Kerning effect.
>
> https://github.com/aritraroy/KerningViews