# What's the width of this UIView with a custom drawRect method?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I have a custom UILabel subclass.  The only method I'm overriding is the `drawRect` method, [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063268/is-it-possible-to-alter-the-letter-spacing-kerning-of-a-font-with-cocoa-touch).

When I pass the UILabel's `bounds.size` or `frame.size` or `layer.bounds.size` to `- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size` I am returned the value that the UILabel *would* be if not for the custom drawing.  That is, the CGSize returned has too small a width since I'm increasing the spacing between letters.

What is the proper way to get the correct width, accounting for my custom drawing?

Answer (score 2):

The proper way is to override `sizeThatFits:` yourself to compute the proper size.  UIKit can't do it for you.

Comment: I understand that I'll need to override `sizeThatFits:` - but how do I compute the proper size?  I can't find a Core Graphics method that will return the dimensions of whatever I just drew, and I'm not sure how to get the size of a specific letter in my UILabel.