# Overloaded method in obj-c category: how to pass it to original class?

Tags: objective-c, categories, overloading

As I know, in my overloaded method (in category) I may call `[super method]` to pass it to original class.
In my case I don't have header file of class, so I write:

```
@interface OriginalClass : NSObject
@end

@interface OriginalClass (overloadMethod)
-(void) method;
@end

@implementation OriginalClass (overloadMethod)
-(void) method
{
    // some my code
    [super method]; // here is warning that "NSObject may not respond to '-method'
}
@end
```

So is it possible to pass `method` to `OriginalClass` correctly without having its header file? Maybe it would be better to look at `method_setImplementation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i remember correctly, the intro to ObjC programming in the docs mentions that when you override a method with a category, you can no longer access the original method.

Your question is pretty much identical to the one here: [How do I call the original function from the overloaded function in a category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514692/how-do-i-call-the-original-function-from-the-overloaded-function-in-a-category)

Note the quote from the docs in the first answer

Answer (score 2):

You're adding a category, not a subclass. When adding a category, think of it as tacking your own methods on to the existing class. Instead of sending messages to `super` (which in this case is `NSObject`), just send them to `self`. Imagine you're in the implementation of the class that you're adding a category to.

I'm not sure if you think you're subclassing or if you're trying to swizzle...

Comment: Excuse my ignorance on this matter, but wouldn't `[self method]` amount to a recursive call of the same method?

Comment: According to Apple docs `super` in categories means original class. The same question is discussed but not solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405060/using-super-in-an-objective-c-category

Comment: @Monolo Yes, it would. That's why I'm trying to figure out why you're overriding methods in a category.

Comment: There is link to working solution in parallel thread (linked in my earlier comment): http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/supersequent-implementation.html It works! But some people on forums worry about deep hacking...