# How to display barcode in iPhone

Tags: iphone, sdk, barcode

I need to show barcode string(example :1001847983) into barcode image in A UIView.  Does the iPhone SDK supports barcode fonts?
I don't need reading the barcode, I just want to show the string in barcode lines.

Answer (score 2):

Learn how to add custom fonts to your app

[Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)

Then find yourself a barcode font

http://www.google.com/search?q=barcode+fonts

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no built-in way to display barcodes. You'll have to create a custom view to convert and display them yourself. Simplest way would probably be to make each black line an opaque, empty UIView and add a lot of them with the correct frames to a UIView subclass.

Built-in iPhone fonts are here:

http://daringfireball.net/2007/07/iphone_fonts

Comment: If you don't understand what that means, you need to learn a little more about UIKit. Here's a good starting point: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html