# NSAttributedString Strikethrough makes my attributed text disappear

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsattributedstring

I am trying to make an attributed string with a strikethrough. I can set other attributes such as foreground color and font size but when I try to set a strikethrough through part of the text, that part of the text disappears. Any Idea what might be causing it?

Below is the code. Thanks for looking!

```
// ...    
    //Price
    NSLog(@"RESULT NUMBER %d", cell.result.resultId);
    priceString = (priceString == nil) ? @"$150.00\n$100.00" : priceString;
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:priceString];
    NSRange linebreak = [priceString rangeOfString:@"\n"];



    if (linebreak.location != NSNotFound) {
        [attributedString beginEditing];
        // RegPrice
        NSRange firstLine = NSMakeRange(0, linebreak.location);
//        [attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
//                                 value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11]
//                                 range:firstLine];
        [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                                 value:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.7 green:0.7 blue:0.7 alpha:1]
                                 range:firstLine];
        @try {
            [attributedString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                                     value:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)
                                     range:firstLine];
        } @catch (NSException *e) {
            NSLog(@"ATTRIBUTE EXCEPTION: %@", e);
        }

        // Sale Price
        [attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                                 value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]
                                 range:NSMakeRange(linebreak.location + 1, priceString.length - (linebreak.location + 1))];
        [attributedString endEditing];
    }
    cell.lblPrice.attributedText = attributedString;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem of string disappearing until I realised that the value for `NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName` should be an NSNumber.

Therefore the code above should look like:

Objective-c

```
[attributedString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName 
                         value: [NSNumber numberWithInt: NSUnderlineStyleSingle] 
                         range:firstLine];
```

In Swift 4 attributes are passed using dictionary of type `[NSAttributedStringKey: Any]` and the strike trough style attribute would look like this:

```
[NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle: NSNumber(value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue)]
```

Comment: This is the only answer here that worked for me. It is clearly a bug / not what Apple intended...

Comment: Happy that helped. Not sure that is a bug, but is definitely not very "swifty"

Comment: Thank you so much!! This saved me!

Answer (score 0):

For me boldSystemFontOfSize: returns a font object with the HelveticaNeueInterface-MediumP4 font. Are you sure this font has a strike-through? Not all fonts do. Maybe try using a different font, one that you know has a strike-through.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good thought. However, I tried switching it to arial and did not seem to work. Do you know any font that does support strikethrough?

Comment: I don't. I had this same problem and eventually got fed up and drew the stirke-through lines myself as suggested by this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2489560/2033515

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem with the strikethrough text disappearing in a UILabel in iOS 7.0 only. It works fine in iOS 6.1 and 7.1.

There seems to be a bug in iOS 7.0 that strikethrough text disappears if the label is too high for the text by a certain amount. It works when I set the label's frame to a small enough height or call sizeToFit after setting the attributedText.