# Format text label when selecting UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uilabel, strikethrough

I'm working on a shopping list app, and I'm wanting to format the text as `strikethrough` when selecting a cell, not quite sure how to implement this.

I'm assuming I should toggle this effect in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, but I'm not sure.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey got some links for you ,might be helpful for you. Also got answer to strike-through for iOS version below 6.

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133014/uilablel-with-text-striked-iphone)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489530/strike-through-font-in-objective-c)

I got below code working for iOS 6 and above

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"PROVIDE_YOUR_STRING"];
[attString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] range:NSMakeRange(0,[attString length])];

_label.attributedText = attString;
```

Comment: what happened ? you changed your answer choice ? anythning missing here ! @ENG618

Comment: No, must have happened on accident.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way to do it but it's definitely a way

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:cell.textLabel.text];
    [attributeString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                            value:@2
                            range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributeString length])];

    [attributeString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributeString length])];

    cell.textLabel.attributedText = attributeString;
```

You can change the color of the strikethrough as you please.

Comment: would this go in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method?

Comment: You can use this in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to make the text `strikethrough` and in `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` you can toggle it to previous state.