# Using a UIWebView, can I use a custom font?

Tags: iphone, fonts, uiwebview, iphone-sdk-3.0, custom-font

I've seen all the talk on the web about the difficulty of using a custom font in iPhone OS. Is it possible, to load a font from within my bundle into the UIWebView component?

EDIT: I saw it in the app called "Omer" by "Rusty Brick"... It seems to be a web view, because I see a delay and during the loading delay the custom area is white. What other component could this have been?

EDIT2: I contacted Rusty Brick. They told me which font it was. A standard font.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is possible to load custom fonts into your UIWebView in iOS3.2 and above. Add the font to your bundle (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application/2616101#2616101)) then just reference the font in your UIWebView's stylesheet like you would any other font:

```
<style type='text/css'>font { font-family: DroidSerif; } </style>
```

Comment: @Moshe Just an innocent example font ;)

Comment: This answer is only half-right.  The other half is referenced in the answer below by @tscheepers--you need to add the font name to your .plist file.  _AND_ one final thing. If you want to use a variant of a font (say DroidSerif Italic) then you need to do two things: first, add the DroidSerif Italic.ttf font to the bundle and the .plist, _then_, when you reference it in your stylesheet, enter the font-family as "DroidSerif-Italic" (note the dash instead of space).

Comment: @sgress454 Even though DroidSerif-Italic doesn't represent a family name, it represents a font name inside the family, but it did the trick, you are a saver ;)

Comment: Indeed this answer is not, really, correct.  Answer below is correct.

Answer (score 8):

It is possible, but you need to make certain to add the `Fonts provided by application` key-value pair to the Info.plist.

I learned about it in this tutorial: http://tetontech.wordpress.com/2010/09/03/using-custom-fonts-in-your-ios-application/

I tried it with a `LWFM` and a `FFIL` font suitcase, but this didn't work. In the end I needed the `TTF` file of the font.

When referencing the font in your code use the PostScript name. To get the correct name for your font, open the `Font Book` application, select the font and click on the `i` in the upper left corner to open the information panel.

[image: Fontbook screenshot]

Comment: This answer is half-right: see my comment above on @Willster's post.

Comment: This answer worked for me on: iOS 6.0, iOS 5.1. Not tested on iOS 4.x