# In Xcode how to add Multiple Paragraphs with Bold Headings?

Tags: ios, xcode, textview, uitextview

In My Application I have a Information Screen In that i am displaying related information. I have a Total 4 pages Text. In the Text There are Several Paragraphs with Bold headings and  Some Bullet points are there

For Example :

My Text is looks like this :

**This is Heading**

This is Paragraph Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting..

**This is Heading 2**

The remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

****The Bullet Points  are given Below :- ****

- desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
  of Lorem Ipsum.
- desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker    including
  versions of Lorem Ipsum. desktop publishing software lik
- Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
- Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

The Above text is example text , like That i have several paragraphs with Bold Headings .
I tried by Using The `TextView`  to display all the information . But I want make Headings should be in bold & points should start with Bulled points .

How can i do this ? can any one give Basic Idea about this please .?

Thanks  In Advance .

Comment: You need to use web view to make your work easier and simple. Just place all of your code in a html file and load that html file in the web view. Hope it helps.

Comment: Text, how to include the fonts for HTML file , Currently i stored my Custom Fonts in Supported folder ? is it possible to call same font to the HTML file also ? Can you give me any example tutorial for this please ..?

Comment: Hi, for custom font you can use css like this
<style type='text/css'>font { font-family: DroidSerif; } </style>
Before that just include your fonts in the bundle and add it into plist file too.
Go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535338/using-a-uiwebview-can-i-use-a-custom-font

Comment: Hi , I added the Html File Using the Web View , The Content is not displaying full ,to display the full HTML page content do i need to add any code for that .. ?

Comment: If everything in your HTML is correct then it will display the whole content. Do check whether you have written all of your content to be displayed inside the <body> </body> tag or not.

Comment: Yes Finally i did it successfully , But i am facing small issue in that ,i.e, in the HTML File i have a 4 Hyperlinks so for that i gave linking like this <a href="https://www.google.com.bh/" target="new">Link</a>. The thing is the link is not redirecting to the safari its loading on the same screen but i want the link should open with safari ? how can do this ?

Comment: For that you have to grab events in you code and open the link manually using openURL method of UIApplication sharedApplication,

Comment: can you give me any reference tutorial or sample code please.. ?

Comment: Go through this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4070

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Attributed Text` property of the `UITextView` in the Property inspector and achieve the bold text (I don't know whether you can achieve the bullets in this way)

[image: Text]

Comment: Thanks for your answer , In the Attributed Text property how to set Bold Text , I can see only Align Property , Text Color , Text Background color & More but i cannot See Bold Type . ?

Comment: @user3744932: select the text and click the font, select the bold attribute from there