# Multiple Text bold UITextView in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I need to bold a text. Kind of paragraph and heading.

Example:
Xamarin.iOS UITextView some text **bold** and some text with **header**

In the above example, I need to make bold and Header bold in Textview.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used HTML string to set bold because I have localization in my application.

```
public NSAttributedString ConvertBoldTextUsingHtml(string htmlString)
{
   var err = new NSError();
   var atts = new NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributes
   {
        DocumentType = NSDocumentType.HTML,
        StringEncoding = NSStringEncoding.UTF8
    };
   return new NSAttributedString(NSData.FromString(htmlString), atts, ref err);
}
textView.AttributedText= ConvertBoldTextUsingHtml(htmlString)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it in code , i see you've got the answer [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/183139/bold-non-bold-text-in-textview).

**Another way** : you could set attribute string directly in storyboard ,it is more simple and Intuitive.

Set Text style as `Attributed` first , select the text and click font in properties menu , you could set bold and font size for all the headers ,refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24304569/8187800) .

---

However , I test it in `Visual Studio for mac` and `Visual Studio for windows` .

This feature works fine with the first one, but not supported in `visual studio for windows` .

So you can only do it in `vs for mac` .

[image]