# iPhone Fonts: set small-caps

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, fonts, typography

i'm branding an iphone app and the designer wants to display list items using Georgia. This is not a big deal, but he wants them do appear as small-caps..

is this possible to do in iPhone os3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by 'list item' you mean a `UITableViewCell`; if so, you can change the font family and size by setting the `textLabel.font` property in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // setup cell
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:10];
    // return cell
}
```

**Update:** Ah, I just noticed you're looking for small caps, not a small font size; whoops. As far as I know there's no easy way to do it. You could try loading a small caps font yourself, which seems [ridiculously painful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application).

Comment: This won't make the label display in *small-caps*.