# iphone objective-c custom font

Tags: iphone, fonts

how can I load and embed a custom font in my iphone app? what font file types are supported? (otf, ttf...)

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to supply fonts with your app and use them. Take a look at CGFontCreateWithDataProvider which should provide all the functionality you need.

At least TTF is supported, not sure about OTF.