# Package custom fonts in a Monotouch assembly

Tags: fonts, xamarin.ios

I have an iPad app that uses custom fonts though the **UIAppFonts** elements in the Info.plist of the primary executable, [as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927348/monotouch-bundle-font-with-binary). I was wondering if there is a way to package those fonts in a reusable assembly so I can share the fonts across several applications. Can a Monotouch assembly contain an Info.plist of its own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MonoTouch does not currently have a way of packaging partial Info.plist that are later merged with the main Info.plist.

It is a good idea, could you file a bug report on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com?