# how to use custom font in iphone application

Tags: iphone, ipad, fonts

how to use custom font in iphone application?
i need to use in custom font in my iphone / ipad appliaction. Can i embed custom font in my application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
http://www.perfectline.co.uk/blog/uiappfonts-custom-fonts-with-the-iphoneipad-3-2-sdk

I am quite sure I saw a sample in WWDC sessions, you could look also the videos ;)