# How can we use custom font in an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)

How can I customize font in my iPhone app?
Is it possible?
How can I use this custom font in a `UILabel`?

I am trying to add `MYRIADPRO-SEMIBOLD.OTF` font in my App.

and the code is

```
UIFont *customFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MYRIADPRO-SEMIBOLD" size:35]; 
titleLbl.font = customFont;
```

And the Plist is

[image]

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try the steps below:

**1. Make configuration in the info.plist as shown in Image**

[image]

**2. Now you should use that added file**

```
UIFont *customFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"fontName" size:size];

// further you may set That Font to any Label etc.
```

**EDIT:** Make Sure you have added that file in your resources Bundle.

[image]

Comment: @Dev you should pass the Name of That File from which you want to use Font.and see my edit.Make Sure you have added that file in your resources Bundle.

Comment: @Dev This is the solution, it works. Be sure you added the font file to the resources folder. And when you set the font in the source code use : (for instance if you want to use bolda.ttf) [UIFont fontWithName@"bolda" size:15];  (do not add .ttf)

Comment: No ashbay, this is not working for me.Iam adding like UIFont *customFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MYRIADPRO-SEMIBOLD" size:35];

    titleLbl.font = customFont;

Comment: @Dev have you added `Custom file` in your resource bundle?

Comment: Yeah I added file to the resource folder

Comment: @Dev it can not be possible. just check again under the `Target ->buildPhase-->Copy bundle Resource` find whether the file is available or not.if not just drag and drop into that place.see my edit

Comment: Kamarshad, The file is available there..

Comment: @dev can you put your code which you were using ?

Comment: Yeah..sure.. I have edited the question. please check

Comment: Yeah... Now it working... Once more downloaded a new font file and place it in the resource folder... Thank you so much... :)

Comment: The important bit is that the name referenced in `fontWithName:size:` may not be the same as file name. On a Mac, if you open the font with Font Book (default app), it will show the correct name in the title bar. You can rename the file but the *font name* will not change.

Answer (score 5):

1. Copy your font file into Resources.
2. In your application .plist create (if it exists just create a row) a row called `Fonts provided by application` and then in `item 0` copy your font name for example `Ciutadella-Bold.otf`
3. Then you can define this font in your application:

   ```
   UIFont *CiutadellaBold = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Ciutadella-Bold" size:17.0f];
   ```
4. And use it in for instance in `UILabel`:

   ```
   [uiLabel setFont:CiutadellaBold];
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It is totally possible. Please check the following links to implement your solution.

[iPhone Development: how to use custom fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462852/iphone-development-how-to-use-custom-fonts)

[How to add custom fonts to an iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837965/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-an-iphone-app)

[how to use custom font in iphone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510301/how-to-use-custom-font-in-iphone-application)

[Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)

I hope these links help.