# Custom Fonts wont work on device?

Tags: iphone, ios, fonts

I've just tried running my application on my iOS device(iphone 4 running IOS 6)

On the iPhone simulator it worked perfectly with Custom fonts?

But on device it goes to default font?

I use a custom class for my font here:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
     self.font = [UIFont fontWithName@"TOONISH" size:self.font.pointSize];
}
```

The class inharets UILabel

Comment: is the custom font being copied to the device?  How did you add it to the project?

Comment: I added it via the Fonts provided by application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have more work to do to get a font working on the device.

Check this link:
[Use custom fonts in iPhone App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029660/use-custom-fonts-in-iphone-app)

You can also try the font on a lable, instead of the class, to verify the issue.

```
UIFont *toonishFont= [UIFont fontWithName:@"TOONISH-Bold" size:12.0f];
[uiLabel setFont:toonishFont];
```

Comment: This blog entry is pretty detailed also, http://www.perfectline.ee/blog/uiappfonts-custom-fonts-with-the-iphoneipad-3-2-sdk   - is toonish a ttf font?

Comment: Yes, Toonish is a ttf font.

Comment: ok, should def be working, you might want to try it with a label to see if the font is actually the problem, or class is the issue.  [uiLabel setFont:tonnish];  Also check value of self.font.pointSize

Comment: I've just tried the setFont it still does work on the Simulator but not on the Device?

Comment: Okay! Fixed something was wrong with the size i gave i think. Thanks alot!