# iOS Font closest to MS Song font

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, fonts, uifont

What font on iOS is closest to the MS Song font on Windows?  I'm trying to create a cross platform program, but I want it to be able to format nicely so i'm looking for a similar font.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any font in iOS app.

To use any font you need .TTF file.

You can get font file for MS song font from this link: [MS Song Font](http://www.fonts2u.com/ms-song.font)

Click on Download button and you will get .ZIP file which contan .TXT and .TTF file

You can use this .ttf file with just two step

1. Make configuration in info.plist to add this .ttf file
2. Use That Added File in creating UIFont Object

To see how to do this two step in detail visit : [Use custom fonts in iPhone App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029660/use-custom-fonts-in-iphone-app?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

To use this font please download its ttf file from [here](http://www.fileswap.com/dl/x4wy2q8Jxs/) . Add it to the main bundle.

Check the following links and tutorials on how to add custom fonts.

[Custom Fonts Tutorial](http://tetontech.wordpress.com/2010/09/03/using-custom-fonts-in-your-ios-application/)

[How to use custom fonts in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376941/how-to-use-custom-fonts-in-iphone-sdk)

[Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)