# Why is this label appearing unstyled?

Tags: ios, fonts, uilabel

I have, in starting to programmatically develop a screen, the following:

```
NSInteger offset = 0;
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Scurlock" size:80];
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(20, 40 + offset, width, 20))];
[label setFont:font];
[label setText:@"Hello, world!"];
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

The "Hello, world!" does appear at the intended coordinates, but I have not found a way to change either the font family or font size. Scurlock is a TrueType font included in the app's resources.

How can I say "Display this text in that font at these coordinates" with a UILabel or something comparable like an RTLabel (which I managed to get bold, but not change the font or font size)?

--EDIT--

I have Scurlock.TTF at the top of Supporting Files and the following from the plist:

```
<key>Fonts provided by application</key>
<array>
    <string>Scurlock.TTF</string>
</array>
```

This results in one 0 in the list printed out for one answer, and the behavior is AFAICT the same whether I specify Scurlock or Scurlock.TTF.

Comment: Are you sure the font's name is really "Scurlock" and not some variant of that? Verify that `font` isn't `nil`.

Comment: Font is nil. I added in Scurlock explicitly to the project (I hadn't--oops), and now opening the font's folder in finder, right-clicking, and selecting "Get Info" gave a name of "Scurlock".

Comment: That's the family name, not the font name.

Comment: It isn't working yet. Should I be specifying "Scurlock.TTF Scurlock" somewhere?

Comment: Run the code in the answer by Peter and look for a font name (not family name) that comes from your Scurlock TTF file. also make sure your file is really named "Scurlock.TTF" and not "Scurlock.ttf". Case matters.

Comment: I had run that code earlier, and ran it again. It didn't load any form of Scurlock. The code has identical case to the filename (Scurlock.TTF). The font I have is available from http://JonathansCorner.com/project/Scurlock.TTF

Answer (score 3):

• Check your target under "Copy Bundle Resources" to make sure that the font is actually included in the bundle.

• Add the font to your plist if you haven't yet.

• Double check the font name using

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", family);
    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
        NSLog(@"  %@", name);
}
```

See [this guide](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/).

Comment: I've added the following to my plist:

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:
[Use custom fonts in iPhone App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029660/use-custom-fonts-in-iphone-app)
Look at the .plist property that you add, and make sure it's the same name as the one you are trying to load.