# iOS: Custom font size doesn't change

Tags: ios, fonts, uilabel, custom-font

I'm trying to implement custom font. This works, however the problem I encounter is that no matter what I set the size of the font, it doesn't listen. I can even set the font size as 5000 and it won't change from font size 20.

```
numberLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Dekar.otf" size:5000.0];
```

The font is properly implemented and is loaded. It's just the size that has problems.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029660/use-custom-fonts-in-iphone-app. See this link...

Comment: How is this link relevant to my question?

Comment: maybe you forgot register plist or something else...

Comment: No, I'm saying that the font loads and displays correctly. The problem I have is with the size not being changed.

Comment: Size set correctly...Take away **.otf** format. But i doubt, that it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size set correctly...Take away **.otf**...