# Use custom font

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

How to use custom font?(font that doesn't exist in iphone)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application

Answer (score 5):

Since you mention `iphone-sdk-4.0` as one of your tags, it means that you can use the `UIAppFonts` key on your app. `UIAppFonts` was introduced on iOS 3.2.

The key to be added on your property list: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW3

[`UIAppFonts` description](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW18).

Answer (score 1):

Ex.
Add the font files to your resource files
Edit your Info.plist: Add a new entry with the key Fonts provided by application.
For each of your files, add the file name to this array

First you can install a custom font in your app pick original font name
then rename your font file name.

[image: original font name]
[LblTwitter  setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"The Great Escape" size:12]];

Note: this is available in iOS 4.0 and later.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to include your font file in your project and update the keys in info.plist after that you can use that font by name see this [link](http://codefriends.blogspot.in/2012/04/adding-custom-font-in-xcode.html)