# How to add custom fonts to an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, fonts

What must I do to get an UIFont object with a custom font? I remember there was also something going on in the Info.plist file.

What font file formats are supported?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)

Comment: Helpful tutorial: http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Answer (score 54, accepted):

To add a custom font to your application, you can add them to the XCode project.  Then, modify the `application-info.plist` file.  Add the key `Fonts provided by application` to a new row.  Add one item for each font you have added.

It supports both TTF and OpenType fonts. One caveat is that it loads and parses all fonts in the startup of your app, so it will slow down the initial load time.

I believe this is only available in iOS 3.2 or later.

Comment: What di i add to the Info.plist? The complete filename or?

Comment: yourprojectname-Info.plist is complete filename.

Comment: can this be done on the fly? I will download font.ttf from net and then I want to use that

Comment: @Durgaprasad 'Obviously' not, since you need to add each font to the plist file.  You can't modify that in-flight, as far as I'm aware -- and you'd have to restart the app afterwards anyway.

Answer (score 2):

## Programming way (Swift)

Add the fonts to your project at the resource folder

And add this function:

```
func loadFont(filePath: String) {

    let fontData = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath)!

    let dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(fontData)
    let cgFont = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(dataProvider)!

    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    if !CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(cgFont, &error) {
        let errorDescription: CFStringRef = CFErrorCopyDescription(error!.takeUnretainedValue())
        print("Unable to load font: %@", errorDescription)
    }
}
```

Use example:

```
if let fontPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MyCustomFont", ofType: "ttf") {
    loadFont(fontPath)
}

let myFont = UIFont(name: "MyCustomFont", size: CGFloat(18))
```