# Journal font in UITextview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, fonts, uitextview

How can the font for a  `UITextview` be set to a [journal font](http://www.dafont.com/journal.font)?

```
[textview setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
```

Any fonts related to journal would also work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837965/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-an-iphone-app

Comment: Check this tutorial http://attila.tumblr.com/post/22319634875/damn-custom-fonts-ios-again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have added the font file as a custom font entry in the info.plist to use it in the first place because it is not included in iOS(i guess you know that just saying). Then the tricky part is to know the exact names of the fonts in the included file wit the exact case.