# How to apply Pictos font to UIButton in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, pictos

I want to use Home button with home icon, but I want to use actual font instead of graphics.

For e.g) I will set UIButton title to "H" and set Pictos font it, so that it should automatically convert button text into corresponding graphics(In this case home icon)

How to do it using pictos font?

Comment: What is pictos font? Can you show your code?

Comment: For that you have to first install the font to that application..Plz refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837965/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-an-iphone-app ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737788/custom-fonts-in-ios-7 these two answers it may help you

Comment: use custom fonts and derive UIButton class.

Comment: @ John Woods: Pictos font can be use as normal font like others to set icon to button. So instead of creating image and assign to button we can use this font to show different icons on button. For more details: http://pictos.cc/font/

Comment: @ Albin Joseph,  Ramshad: Thanks will try...

Comment: You don't need a UIButton subclass but you will need to set the font in code. Unless the betas have done this recently fonts you install through the UIAppFonts key won't show up in the IB font selectors.

Comment: @AlbinJoseph, Ramshad, Johnwoods, Adam Eberbach: Thanks for help. Finally I got this Pictos font in Photoshop. Please see my answer for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got "Pictos" font in .otf format from photoshop. Pictos font is available in photoshop.

Steps:

1. Export Pictos font in .otf format from photoshop.
2. Add custom font to your application, you can add them to the XCode project.
3. Modify the application-info.plist file. Add the key "Fonts provided by application" to a
   new row. Add one item for pictos font you have added.
   [image]
4. Create button and set Pictos font.

   ```
   UIButton *homeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   homeButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 34 , 33);
   [homeButton setTitle:@"H" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   homeButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Pictos" size:22];
   ```
5. You will see button with Home icon like
   [image]

Note: You can set different icons by setting proper title text.
[image]