# How to handle tvOS fonts SpriteKit

Tags: swift, fonts, sprite-kit, tvos

How do you guys handle converting your iOS games to tvOS in regards to fonts?

tvOS hardly supports any fonts available on iOS and therefore my game menus etc just look plain and boring on the appleTV.

I understand that Apple wants to use SanFrancisco style fonts for apps for legibility, which makes sense. 
For Spritekit games however those fonts dont look good at all, especially when having cartoonish style artdesign.

Is there any trick to get fonts such as Chalkduster, Damascus etc to work on tvOS in code without having to resort do do all the menus in Photoshop just for the appleTV.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You can use custom fonts. Just include the font file in your application. [How to add custom fonts to an iPhone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3837965/2108547)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check on google how to do this, never done it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel Storm so kindly pointed out to use custom fonts beyond the supported ones I can follow this stack overflow question

[How to add custom fonts to an iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837965/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-an-iphone-app)