# Name of non-system font in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, fonts, uifont

I want to add a non-system font to my iPhone/iPad app.

I have added the font file to the project and also added the font to the `UIAppFonts` property of the info.plist.

To load the font I'm using `fontWithName` of `UIFont`. But the *name* of the font does not seem to be the file name, with or without extension, nor the name that appears in Font Book.

```
UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"What goes here?" size:10];
```

Where do I find out the *name* of the font?

Comment: You can see here for the detail answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UIFont`'s `+familyNames` and then `+fontNamesForFamilyName:` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Josh! It certainly should, but I can't believe that there's no easier way to find out.

Comment: Great thanks - is there any way of finding out the fontNames wihtout having to run the app?

Comment: @jowie I think there's an app or two in the app store that list fonts (Lorem Ipsum on the iPad, IIRC, don't recall about iPhone). Other than that, there's no other way that I'm aware of...

Answer (score 2):

If you open the ttf file in Font Book on your Mac, the title of the window is the name iOS uses too. (In my case, AvantGarde Bk BT)

[image]