# How do I get the font name from an otf or ttf file?

Tags: ios, uifont

I have used a custom font in my previous app.

The file name was "ProximaNova-Regular.otf" and to load the font I just used...

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Regular" size:20];
```

This worked perfectly.

Now in this new app I have three font files...

```
Dude_Willie.otf
Impact
handsean.ttf
```

But I'm not sure how to load these.

I have tried

```
[UIFont fontWithName:<the file name> size:20];
```

But this just falls back to using Helvetica.

How can I find what name to use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Name of non-system font in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143908/name-of-non-system-font-in-iphone)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding custom fonts to iOS app finding their real names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984937/adding-custom-fonts-to-ios-app-finding-their-real-names)

Comment: @FyodorVolchyok ah. Look at the comments. I disregarded that question already. The problem I was having was that I hadn't installed the fonts properly in the project so listing the `familyNames` didn't actually show the fonts I was looking for.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26053/26227 -- `fc-scan --format "%{foundry}: %{family}\n" filename.ttf` or `filename.otf`.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Right click on the TTF -> Get Info

"Full Name" is what you're looking for.

That's what worked for me with TTFs.

**Edit:**

I just used a font that had a different name from the "Full Name" in Get Info.

For the compilation of this answer, If the quick check above doesn't work, run this code in your project:

```
for (NSString *fontFamilyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:fontFamilyName]) {
        NSLog(@"Family: %@    Font: %@", fontFamilyName, fontName);
    }
}
```

And search for the correct name of the font you want to use.

Swift 3.0 code:

```
for fontFamilyName in UIFont.familyNames{
    for fontName in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: fontFamilyName){
        print("Family: \(fontFamilyName)     Font: \(fontName)")
    }
}
```

Comment: It really depends on the maker of the font.  We had some horrid fonts that we received from a client, and the font names are seriously arbitrary once they are consumed by iOS.  I just tried this method with one of our fonts and it failed.

Comment: @borrrden so far this method worked for me every time. I never created a font my self so you might be right, I don't know.

Comment: It will most likely work for well-made fonts.  The fonts we got were created about 2 decades ago (it was bad...).  However, the only way to be sure is to ask the system.

Comment: @borrrden or to take 2 seconds to right click and try the name showing up there. :) If that doesn't work ~ then the digging starts..

Comment: Thanks, this worked after I had properly installed the fonts in the info.plist file.

Comment: Not sure if this is a hard and fast case, but if the 'Full Name' has spaces I've always had to replace them with a dash '-'.

Comment: ... or sometimes remove the spaces

Comment: This does not work for all fonts. For example, the "Full Name" value is shown as "Proxima Nova Regular" when the family in code is "ProximaNova-Regular"

Comment: it's hilarious that i'm came here for this font family name question specifically for the "Proxima Nova Regular" font name... thank you @rrbrambley :)

Comment: I got the font name from the Swift 3 code. the Get Info was not the same

Comment: @rrbrambley you should use PostScript name (open Font Book, load/open your font, then switch on info mode and check this PostScript name)

Comment: get info seems to be a nice answer for people who are not aware native iOS development,.

Answer (score 102):

Follow these four easy steps to add and use a new font in your iOS app:

- Add **your_new_font.ttf** or **your_new_font.otf** to your Xcode project
- In your project's info.plist, add a new entry for **your_new_font.ttf** or **your_new_font.otf** to the `UIAppFonts` array (plain text for this one is 'Fonts provided by application')
- At this point, I recommend adding this temporary chunk of debug code to dump all fonts that are accessible by your app, including your newly added your_new_font:

**//Swift**

```
    for family: String in UIFont.familyNames {
        print("\(family)")
        for names: String in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family) {
            print("== \(names)")
        }
    }
```

**//Objective-c**

> ```
> for(NSString *fontfamilyname in [UIFont familyNames]) {
>     NSLog(@"family:'%@'",fontfamilyname);
>     for(NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:fontfamilyname]) {
>         NSLog(@"\tfont:'%@'",fontName);
>     }
>     NSLog(@"-------------");
> }
> ```

- In the debug output, look for your new font's 'family' and 'font' name. Pass whatever is displayed as the 'font' name corresponding to your new font family (there could be more than one 'font' associated with your new font 'family') to `UIFont *myNewFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"font_name_from_debug_output" size:20]` and you should be in business!

Answer (score 87):

- Install the font
- Open Font Book app on your Mac
- Select the font and click on 'info' button
- The name you're looking for is **PostScript name**

  - MacOS: View -> Show Font Info

[image: example]

Comment: seems like the simplest way

Comment: fwiw, I needed to go View > Show Font Info in order to see the details. Not sure why it was off by default on my machine.

Answer (score 48):

**To use fonts in iOS, you have to load the font based on the font's *FULL NAME* (PostScript Name), which is sometimes (and usually is) different from the font's actual *FILE NAME*.**

> Imagine yourself renaming the Font file "Arial-regular.ttf" to be
>   "foo.ttf". The font contained inside the font file you just renamed is still
>   "Arial-regular".

There are some good programmatic ways to get the font name already on this thread, but I have a different approach using the command line.

If you are on a Mac or Linux, simply run this script from the command line in the directory where you have your custom fonts (uses the `fc-scan` utility from [fontconfig](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig/) which is probaly already installed, but if not you can install it via homebrew: `brew install fontconfig`):

```
for file in "$arg"*.{ttf,otf}; do fc-scan --format "%{postscriptname}\n" $file; done
```

Here is a screenshot of the above command running on my `~/Library/Fonts` directory:

[image]

The script above will run through all the `.ttf` and `.otf` files in the current directory, then print out the **PostScript Name** for each font which you can use to reference the font file in XCode or elsewhere.

If you want to get fancy with some additional information (PostScriptName, Filename) and some color coding, you can run this alternative script:

```
for file in "$arg"*.{ttf,otf}; do 
    postscriptname=$(fc-scan --format "%{postscriptname}\n" $file);
    printf "\033[36m PostScript Name:\033[0m %s \e[90m(%s)\033[0m\n" "$postscriptname" "$file";
done
```

[image]

This is a bit faster than copy-pasting code inside of your AppDelegate.m file to print out the names every time you want to add a new font file, which is the popular method, and it's also faster than opening the Font in FontBook to inspect the PostScript Name.

**USEFUL TIP:** If you alias the above script in your terminal so that all you need to do is type a single command to get all the PostScript font names for all the files in the current directory (my function is called `fontnames` so all I have to do is type `fontnames` at the terminal inside the directory with fonts in it, and the PostScript names will be printed automatically, then you will save time in your development workflow and have this handy script ready to use when you need it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am using Mac. I downloaded fontConfig from the link u provided. But it has so many files in it. How do I use it or install fontConfig to my mac.

Comment: @SujayUN If you are on a Mac, you might already have the `fc-scan` utility installed. What happens when you run `fc-scan -V` on the terminal?

Comment: You can also install fontConfig via [homebrew](https://brew.sh/): `brew install fontconfig` .

Comment: I get this when I ran ur cmd -bash: fc-scan: command not found

Comment: Ok, I recommend that you install via Homebrew if you don't have it installed on your machine. See the link to Homebrew and install command in my comment above.

Comment: Second script was just what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

If you want to find the font name for a given font file programmatically:

```
import Foundation

func loadFontName(for file: URL) throws -> String {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: file)

    guard let provider = CGDataProvider(data: data as CFData) else {
        throw Error("Could not create data provider")
    }

    guard let font = CGFont(provider) else {
        throw Error("Could not load font")
    }

    guard let name = font.postScriptName else {
        throw Error("Could not get font name from font file")
    }

    return name as String
}
```

Replace with your own throwable `Error` objects as required.

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 4.0+** solution

```
    for fontFamilyName in UIFont.familyNames {
        print("family: \(fontFamilyName)\n")

        for fontName in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: fontFamilyName) {
            print("font: \(fontName)")
        }
    }
```

Will output:

> family: Apple SD Gothic Neo
>
> font: AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin
>
> font: AppleSDGothicNeo-Light

Answer (score 5):

You want to know how to get name go for this :-

```
  NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];

  for (NSInteger indFamily=0; indFamily<[familyNames count]; ++indFamily) 
  {
        NSLog(@"Family name: %@", [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]);

        NSArray *fontNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
              [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:[familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]]];

        for (NSInteger indFont=0; indFont<[fontNames count]; ++indFont) 
        {
              NSLog(@"    Font name: %@", [fontNames objectAtIndex:indFont]);
        }
  }
```

hope it helps you...

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3.0

```
for familyName in UIFont.familyNames {
        for fontName in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName ) {
            print("\(familyName) : \(fontName)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

After you've added your fonts to your project/app, add this code (probably just in app delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method) in order to print out all the available fonts for your app.  From with-in that list you should be able to identify the font you're after. Don't forget to remove the unnecessary code after.

```
for (NSString *fontFamilyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:fontFamilyName]) {
        NSLog(@"Family: %@    Font: %@", fontFamilyName, fontName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use otfinfo --info arial.ttf to get the name from command line. The postscript name is the one you need to pass to the UIFont constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 1.2:

```
    for familyName in UIFont.familyNames() {
        for fontName in UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName as! String) {
            println("\(familyName) : \(fontName)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Another "quick, practical" hack that doesn't involve scanning through all the default fonts that exist on either the emulator or device is to use the font for something in your `storyboard`. Then if you edit the storyboard with a text editor (open as `source code`), you can see the fonts used with "internal" names if you search for the "customFonts" tag:

```
<customFonts key="customFonts">
    <array key="Linotype - AvenirNextLTPro-Bold.otf">
        <string>AvenirNextLTPro-Bold</string>
    </array>
    <array key="Linotype - AvenirNextLTPro-Regular.otf">
        <string>AvenirNextLTPro-Regular</string>
    </array>
    <array key="TradeGothicLTPro-BdCn20.otf">
        <string>TradeGothicLTPro-BdCn20</string>
    </array>
</customFonts>
```

Answer (score 1):

Log familyNames of font file and then access the fonts:

```
// You can log all font family names suing **fontNamesForFamilyName**

NSLog(@" font name %@", [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"the file name"]);
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for us - If the Filename is different from the font family name it fails

Comment: You should get the font name in get info.

Answer (score 0):

List font names and families for **macOS** with **Swift 4.1**:

```
NSFontManager.shared.availableFonts.map { print($0) }
NSFontManager.shared.availableFontFamilies.map { print($0) }
```

Answer (score -2):

**Swift 4.0 Supported**

This is only one line code for print all font family and it's font's names

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Main line of code
    UIFont.familyNames.sorted().forEach({ print($0); UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: $0 as String).forEach({print($0)})})
}
```

Comment: Read the question.

Comment: @Fogmeister Your accepted answer is same like this that's why I write this code in shorter way..

Comment: This line read the ttf or otf file and then give font family and it's all fonts name.. @Fogmeister

Comment: If the accepted answer is the same as yours... why are you writing this one? Just edit the one that already exists (That's what the edit button is for). Don't try to steal other people rep points by copy pasting their answers for minor, insignificant changes. I have now changed the accepted question to a more recent one that shows how to properly install the fonts. Thanks

Comment: Also, your answer is "only one line of code" but it is pretty much unreadable. I'd prefer an answer that has multiple lines that can easily be scanned over to see what it is doing.