# Embedding ttf fonts doesn't work perfectly Obj C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, font-embedding

I'm trying to embed the Open Sans font family (ttf files) into Obj c. I've added them to my info.plist and I'm able to use some of the fonts, but (for instance) the OpenSans-CondLight.ttf font doesn't show up when I check all the fonts embedded. Anyone got a possible explanation for this? There is nothing wrong with the ttf files.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: I don't think there is much code to show. it's embedded in my info.plist as i told.

Comment: How are you calling the UIFont in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Likely the name of the font file is different than the font name itself.  I would look for the font name.  You can get this by going to the TFF -> Right Clicking -> Get Info -> "Full Name" (See: [How do I get the font name from an otf or ttf file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788330/how-do-i-get-the-font-name-from-an-otf-or-ttf-file)).

Comment: Great! Will you mark my answer as correct so it stays at the top of the page for others?

Comment: Was waiting for the 2 minutes to pass. ;)