# Xamarin.Forms: custom font and FontAttributes

Tags: android, ios, fonts, xamarin.forms, attributes

I work on a **Xamarin.Forms project** where I added 2 **Google fonts**: [Montserrat](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat) and [RobotoCondensed](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Condensed).

I can use these fonts without any problem in my app, with Labels or Buttons, on iOS and Android.

But when I try to apply a `FontAttributes` like `Italic` or `Bold`, this doesn't work.

I've first only added the "main" font ("Montserrat-Regular" and "RobotoCondensed-Regular"). Then I've added "secondary" fonts ("Italic", "Bold", "BoldItalic") but this doesn't change anything.

***Is there something I'm doing wrong?***

Answer (score 1):

- You need to include `RobotoCondensed-Bold` font as well to apply bold effect, by only having `RobotoCondensed` font you can't apply that effect.
- For custom fonts you need to add those fonts to achieve effects.
- Where ever you want to apply `bold` or `Italic` fonts, use those fonts like `RobotoCondensed-Bold` or `RobotoCondensed-Italic`.

You can refer this link for the same: https://xamarinhelp.com/custom-fonts-xamarin-forms/

Hope this may solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

As explained [in this blog post](https://blog.xamarin.com/custom-fonts-in-ios/) and mentioned [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts), you need to add all the font styles you want. e.g. `RobotoCondensed-bold`, `RobotoCondensed-regular` and `RobotoCondensed-italic`.

Then you can reference them in a platform-specific way. On android, a font that you placed in `Assets/Fonts` is referred to by the string `Fonts/RobotoCondensed-bold.ttf#RobotoCondensed-bold` where the first part is determined by the filename, and the part after the `#` is the [PostscriptName of the font](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45443858/2550406).
On iOS, you only need the font name.

> `FontFamily = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS ? "Lobster-Regular" : null // set only for iOS`
>
> `FontFamily = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android ? "Lobster-Regular.ttf#Lobster-Regular" : null // set only for Android`

To make referring to fonts easier, you can define a platform-specific style in `App.xaml`:

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="MyFontRegular">
   <On Platform="Android" Value="Fonts/myfont-regular.ttf#MyFont-Regular" />
   <On Platform="iOS" Value="MyFont-Regular" />
</OnPlatform>
```

Set `FontFamily="{StaticResource MyFontRegular}"` to apply this font. This effectively deactivates the effects of `FontAttributes` set on the same element.

If your font styles are simply the common `regular`, `bold` and `italic`, you *can* refer to them using `FontAttributes` by setting `FontFamily="My FontFamily Name"`, where the font family name can be found similarly to how you find the PostscriptName of the font. This option of using the `FontAttributes` is something I just stumbled upon, though. I do not know whether this is documented behaviour. And it does not seem to work for other styles like `dashed` or `medium`. It is also worth pointing out that the result from setting the FontFamily and FontAttributes does not look exactly the same like specifying the exact font with style included. It is possible, that using `FontAttributes` makes Xamarin ignore `FontFamily`.

Comment: As of Xamarin.Forms 4.5.530 and up, there is no need to specify platform, nor add the font files to each of the native projects. Here is a great guide devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/embedded-fonts-xamarin-forms