# using custom bold font in Xcode using UIFont

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have imported all types of my custom font into the Xcode
but when I want to use it in UIFont I got Error

I use like below  :

```
let appearance = UITabBarItem.appearance()
    let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "IRANSansMobile(FaNum)_Bold", size: 10),
                      NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
    appearance.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any], for: .normal)
```

when I delete _Bold from end of my font name it works correctly but not in bold style.
please help me solve it

Comment: I guess that you used the filename instead of the postscript name? Install it in your Mac, open "Font Books.app", Select the bold font, then Cmd+I (show font information), and use the postscript name that is shown. Else, in iOS, add additional code to fetch all the fonts family enumerate and find your bold version.

Comment: For the `Fonts Book.app` version: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79875/how-can-i-get-the-postscript-name-of-a-ttf-font-installed-in-os-x for the "coding" version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788330/how-do-i-get-the-font-name-from-an-otf-or-ttf-file

Answer (score 1):

Code to print out your all available UIFonts. Check the name of the font family and font name. Use this name as your font name.

```
let fontFamilyNames = UIFont.familyNames()
        for familyName in fontFamilyNames {
            //Check the Font names of the Font Family
            let names = UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName )
            // Write out the Font Family name and the Font's names of the Font Family
            print("Font == \(familyName) \(names)")
        }
```