# ffmpeg burned-in subtitles render in the wrong font

Tags: python, c, ffmpeg, libav

Trying to burn in subtitles to a video in FFMPEG in GothamProBold font. No matter what I do it keeps reverting to Helvetica. From the console, I see that FFMPEG seems to load the font without error. Then switches over to font provider "coretext"

```
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x7fed054048c0] Loading font file '/Projects/Fonts/GothaProBol.otf'
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x7fed054048c0] Using font provider coretext
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x7fed054048c0] fontselect: (GothaProBol.otf, 400, 0) -> /System/Library/Fonts/Helvetica.ttc, -1, Helvetica
```

It seems like it has my font loaded, then loads what is likely a system default of Helvetica instead. My guess is that my chosen font isn't **actually** loading after all.

FFMPEG command (called from python) is as follows:

```
ffmpeg_cmd = ["ffmpeg", 
              "-i", self.source_video_uri, 
              "-y",
              "-c:v", "prores", "-profile:v", "1", 
              "-c:a", "pcm_s16be", 
              "-vf", f"subtitles={srt_uri}:fontsdir=/Projects/Fonts:force_style='Fontname=GothaProBol.otf'",
              f"{self.source_video_uri}_render.mov"]

subprocess.call(ffmpeg_cmd)
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: Found this setting in libass header file "ass.h" - which ffmpeg calls when using the subtitle filter. Don't know how to actually *set* this variable when ffmpeg calls libass, but here it is. Line 182:

```
 * \brief Default Font provider to load fonts in libass' database
 *
 * NONE don't use any default font provider for font lookup
 * AUTODETECT use the first available font provider
 * CORETEXT force a CoreText based font provider (OS X only)
 * FONTCONFIG force a Fontconfig based font provider
 *
 * libass uses the best shaper available by default.
 */
typedef enum {
    ASS_FONTPROVIDER_NONE       = 0,
    ASS_FONTPROVIDER_AUTODETECT = 1,
    ASS_FONTPROVIDER_CORETEXT,
    ASS_FONTPROVIDER_FONTCONFIG,
    ASS_FONTPROVIDER_DIRECTWRITE,
} ASS_DefaultFontProvider;
```

**RE: ANSWER BELOW:** For the most part, it seems that if your font is installed in /System/Fonts or /Library/Fonts then CoreText can find it. Though in some cases, the naming conventions can be quite particular and non-intuitive. It also can't seem to find all fonts, necessarily.

For example: Gotham Pro Bold, in the /Library/Fonts folder on my system, file named "GothaProBol.otf" is *correctly* passed to fontname as: GothamPro-Bold or just Gotham Pro. Gotham Pro Bold, GothamPro, Gotham Pro-Bold, GothaProBol, and GothaProBol.otf do NOT work.

For most fonts it seems the preferred convention is {FontName}-{Style/Weight} as displayed in Mac OS's FontBook, not the filename.

That said, I have a novelty 'Game of Thrones.ttf' font in the same folder as Gotham Pro, and I can't get CoreText to connect to it under any of the above naming conventions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788330/how-do-i-get-the-font-name-from-an-otf-or-ttf-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not put the file extension in the font name:

```
force_style='fontname=GothamPro-Bold'
```

In my case I got a file called `GothamPro-Bold.otf` and the output was like this:

```
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x55c809fd73c0] Shaper: FriBidi 0.19.7 (SIMPLE) HarfBuzz-ng 2.6.4 (COMPLEX)
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x55c809fd73c0] Loading font file './fonts/GothamPro-Bold.otf'
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x55c809fd73c0] Using font provider fontconfig
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x55c809fd73c0] fontselect: (GothamPro-Bold, 400, 0) -> GothamPro-Bold, 0, GothamPro-Bold
```

Comment: I removed the file extension, but still get the same result. The culprit I think is that your font is loading from 'fontconfig' and mine is loading from 'coretext.' Coretext I believe is the standard font library on my os. If it doesn't see GothamPro Bold in that folder, it likely returns the default font, in this case helvetica. Any experience setting up fontconfig for ffmpeg? Looks like its a brew install option. For what its worth, I do see 'libfontconfig' enabled when I run "ffmpeg" from the terminal

Comment: I have no idea how to force the usage of fontconfig. Have you tried different formats for the font name? Like `GothamPro`, `Gotham Pro`, `GothamPro Bold`, `Gotham Pro Bold` and so on.

Comment: Update: I found a file called "ass.h" which documents the ASS_DefaultFontProvider variable on line 182 (see above). I'm not sure how to manually set it though, when ffmpeg actually calls libass.

Comment: Your initial answer ultimately is correct, thanks. For some reason it didn't work when I tried, but now it does. The font may not have been in a system folder, but now it's in /Library/Fonts folder, which CoreText finds. Also, the fontsdir parameter seems to do nothing. You are spot on re: the naming conventions too. GothamPro-Bold or just Gotham Pro WORK. Gotham Pro Bold, GothamPro, Gotham Pro-Bold, GothaProBol, and GothaProBol.otf do NOT work. I still wish there was a more absolute / customizable way to pass fonts to fontname, but alas.

Comment: @dv151 this might be a bit late but I got FFMPEG loading custom fonts...have a look at my post below.

Answer (score 2):

I got the custom fonts working in **FFMPEG subtitles filter**.
*(I'm using a Mac and FFMPEG-PYTHON which is just a wrapper around FFMPEG)*.

I also have the font files in a folder local to my project.`(./fonts)` and changing the font file name or using the font name shown in Mac's Font-Book doesn't work.

So here is how I got it working...

1. Open the font file in Font Forge you can download it here - [FontForge](https://fontforge.org).
2. Click on the **Elements tab** and then **Font Info**
3. You can see the font name on the top
   [image: Font Info]
4. Use the font name exactly as you see it as the **FFMPEG** **force_style** args
   `fontsdir='./fonts',force_style='FontName=HelveticaRoundedLTStd-BdCn,PrimaryColour=0x7FFFD4,Fontsize= 26`

Here are my terminal logs showing that it's loading the custom font.

[image: Terminal Logs]

Comment: I still can't use many fonts. For example `CopperplateGothicStd-33BC`, `Moonglow-Ext`, `PenumbraSerifStd-Semibold` and many others which I even never seen before but all are in my Font dir.

Answer (score 1):

I had to specify both a `fontsdir` and a `Fontname`. Here is an example command:

```
ffmpeg -i "/tmp/input.mp4" -vf "subtitles=/tmp/subs.srt:fontsdir=/tmp/fonts:force_style='Fontname=Roboto Regular'" /tmp-output.mp4
```

In this case there was a space between `Roboto` and `Regular`, but sometimes there is a `-` in between.

The *only* way to be sure you're using the correctly spelled fullname, is to run a command on the font file.

This is the Python script I use for that, based on `fc-scan` which works on Mac OS and linux machines:

```
import subprocess
import re

def get_font_fullname(font_path):
    try:
        # Run fc-scan and capture the output
        result = subprocess.run(['fc-scan', font_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

        # Check for errors
        if result.returncode != 0:
            print(result.stderr)
            return None

        # Use regex to find the fullname
        match = re.search(r'fullname: "(.*?)"', result.stdout)

        if match:
            return match.group(1)  # Return the extracted font name
        else:
            print("Font name not found in fc-scan output")
            return None

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return None
```

I then pass the result of `get_font_fullname("/path/to/font.ttf")` into the `Fontname` parameter in the `ffmpeg` command.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to solve the same problem all evening, finally figured it out.

OP said that 'Game of Thrones.ttf' didn't work but 'GothaProBol.otf' did.

So I used an online tool to convert my custom font from .ttf to .otf

Then copied my custom font into /Library/Fonts/fontname.otf

Then used the POSTSCRIPT-NAME from Font Book and it worked beautifully :-)

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "subtitles=subtitle.ass:force_style='Fontname=CUSTOMfontBlack-Regular'" output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue but i resolved it by using the font name as it is. `Bourgeois-UltraBold-Condensed.ttf` will be `...force_style='FontName=Bourgeois UltraBold Condensed'...`