# Displaying custom fonts on the iphone

Tags: iphone, fonts

I have a game which I would like the time and score to be displayed in a custom font.

How does one display their own fonts, or would I need to write an algorithm which controls a list of number images e.g. 1, 2, 3 etc. and displays them e.g. 134

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more info would be useful. When you are just using simple iPhone controls, like an UILabel, you can just add fonts to your project and mention them in the UIAppFonts section of your apps plist.

Otherwise I would suggest using an image map, containing all the characters you need. Cocos2D contains easy stuff for this kind of "problems".