# How to set Custom Font to UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Iam setting custom font to UILabel dynamically through programatically but in Attributes Inspector the custom Font name is not showing .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462852/iphone-development-how-to-use-custom-fonts

Comment: Goto this url...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029660/use-custom-fonts-in-iphone-app

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your custom font with .tiff file also set in .plist `Fonts provide by application`  : set your file name by adding an item.

Comment: can i used it from file inspector

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some additional work to set the custom font.Use this:

[using-custom-fonts-in-ios-application](http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/using-custom-fonts-in-ios-application/)

Comment: Thanks for ur answer.Same thing iam doing, i can set font through code but not showing the name to select directly

Comment: it won't show in the interface builder's properties. you need to set the font of a label with the font name like, [self.labelOutlet setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Sathu" size:10]];

Comment: one important thing is including font name. you must carefully read that section