# UILabel with custom font displays *wrong* custom font

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application/2616101#2616101) method to embed custom fonts in my iPhone app.

The embedding works: When I run the following code, the fonts are listed. (Currently, I'm embedding all family members of Myriad Pro in OTF format)

```
for( NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames] ){
    for( NSString *fntName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName] ){
        NSLog(@"%@", fntName);
}}
```

When I try to set the font of a label to MyriadPro or MyriadPro-Bold, this works just as expected. However, when I set the font to MyriadPro-BoldCond, the label is still set in MyriadPro-Bold instead of the condensed version. (The font names are correct, I checked.) My Code:

```
[recommendationLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-BoldCond" size:140]];
recommendationLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

What's the deal?

**Edit:** In addition to Ingve's solution below, I have found out that – at least for Myriad Pro – the correct font variant gets displayed as soon as I remove unused fonts from the plist. In this case I needed to remove MyriadPro-SemiBold. Mindboggling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UIFont is limited to two variations per font family. However, you can work around this by opening the additional n-2 fonts in an editor and changing the family name.

Answered my own question about this here: [UIFont fontWithName: limited to loading 2 variations per family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715824/uifont-fontwithname-limited-to-loading-2-variations-per-family)

Comment: Is this still true? 4 years later?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is a limitation of UIFont? Have you tried using Core Text?

According to [iOS Core Text Fonts](http://bluecrowbar.com/blog/2010/12/ios-fonts.html), "Core Text doesn’t give you access to more fonts, but it provides support for a lot more font variations. To give an example: Helvetica Neue has 4 variations when you use UIFont whereas it has 11 variations when using Core Text."

Comment: Seems interesting. I'll try and report back.

Comment: And I'm back. Using Core Text does indeed work. However, it's a LOT of work compared to using NSLabel, especially if you've been using Interface Builder to layout your application as I have done.