# do personal fonts carry over?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

if i have a font that I made and use it in my app, will it uploaded with my binary etc and display when i run it on my iphone?

Comment: I don't know much about app making, but I assume it would need to be embedded into your app so that they can view it. At least in web design custom fonts need to be on your server for you to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's in your bundle, it'll go with your app. Using it though is another story. The iPhone doesn't support custom fonts out of the box. You have to write a wrapper on UILabel or whatever to use it. That, or get an open source one.

If you want information on loading your custom fonts, check out this question: [Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)

Comment: "The iPhone doesn't support custom fonts out of the box."

That's no longer correct as of iOS 3.2.

"Custom Font Support
Applications that want to use custom fonts can now include those fonts in their application bundle and register those fonts with the system by including the UIAppFonts key in their Info.plist file. The value of this key is an array of strings identifying the font files in the application’s bundle. When the system sees the key, it loads the specified fonts and makes them available to the application."

Comment: Thanks for the correction @benwong. I hadn't looked at this since iOS 3.2 - I'd only needed it for some small stuff so I made transparent background PNGs of the stuff I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate answer is in the app bundle you build. Locate the bundle (it has file name extension "app") in the Finder, right-click it and select "Show Package Contents". Whatever is there gets into the IPA package distributed to your customers through the App Store.

With regard to fonts included in your app, see benwong's comment. You should add the font files to the Xcode project *and* add all the font names under the key UIAppFonts (aka "Fonts provided by application") to the Info.plist.