# Why are UIFont and CGFont/CTFont separated completely?

Tags: ios, uikit, uifont

I was trying to draw some text with a downloaded font. I looked at API documentation and searched the Web. I found a solution, but the problem is that it's applicable to only the `CoreGraphics` level framework. So I searched for a way to convert `CGFont` to `UIFont`, but there was no way to do this.

I realized `UIFont` and `CGFont/CTFont` are separated completely, even though they're created from same font file. `CGFont` and `CTFont` are convertible from/to each other, but for `UIFont`, the only way is recreating with its attributes like name and size. And applicable codes are also separated.

For instance, `CATextLayer` accepts only `CGFont`/`CTFont` — no `UIFont`. But all `UIKit` controls accept only `UIFont`.

Why does this separation exist? Or am I wrong? (Any way to use a downloaded font in `UIKit` classes?)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The short answer : *"Only Apple folks knows"*

The more detailed answer, after digging *(reversing)* frameworks a bit:

- `UIKit.framework` doesn't use ***at all*** `CGFont` type
- `UIKit.framework` use instead CoreText `CTFont` and `GSFont`...
- `GSFont` comes from... the `GraphicsServices` private framework
- `GraphicsServices`... use `CGFont`

So here is my guess *(Might be completely wrong)* :

- `UIFont` > *`GSFont`(Private)* > `CGFont`
- `UIKit` > `GraphicsServices` > `CoreGraphics` :

  > At least Concerning fonts, Apple engineers have set up an abstraction layer between `UIKit`
  >   and `CoreGraphics` frameworks, via the obscur [`GraphicsServices`](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/GraphicsServices.framework) one.
- `iOS` > `iOS` *(Private)* > `Mac OSX` :

  > Why they did this, I would say `CoreGraphics`, which comes from Mac OSX, wasn't optimal for iOS devices, and `UIKit` being iOS only, they added a layer between both apis. Or more generally they plan one day to separate completely UIKit from CoreGraphics... iOS from Mac OSX... Who knows! *The apple folks does*, my short answer :)

About using custom fonts with `UIKit`, you might be interested reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application).