# How to load font from disk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to load a font from disk and use it during run-time?

If so, how/where do you store the fonts on the iphone/ipod/ipad for your app to use?

(To be clear, I'm not talking about adding the font as a resource at design-time. I'm asking about a way to allow a user to select a font file during run-time, loading it, and making it available for use.)

Answer (score 0):

You should put them (.ttf, .otf) into your info-plist under `UIAppFonts` then you can "use" them with `setFont: withSize:`

Comment: Perhaps I should rephrase my initial question, but I'm trying to load a font from disk at run time - how would I add it to my info-plist?

Answer (score 0):

You add your font as a resource, add it to your info.plist under `Fonts provided by application` (`UIAppFonts`) array, then use it as any embedded one.

---

Ok, in that case take a look at [FontLabel](https://github.com/zynga/FontLabel) project.

One thing though, looking through it's code - you can only get CGFontRef and with kind of voodoo work with it, no conversion between CGFontRef and UIFont really exists. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799128/why-are-uifont-and-cgfont-ctfont-separated-completely)

Comment: Perhaps I should rephrase my initial question, but I'm trying to load a font from disk at run time - how would I add it to my info-plist?