# how can I import new font in xcode using during project

Tags: iphone, fonts, custom-font

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)

hi! everyone, i have a problem I need to insert new font named Apple LiGothic Medium in xcode so that I can use it in my apps.

pls someone help me

Answer (score 6):

Check the below SO post

[Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)

Blog posts:

[Using custom fonts in iPhone applications](http://rcloudsoftware.wordpress.com/2009/06/13/using-custom-fonts-in-iphone-applications/)

[Load custom font in iPhone](http://www.waterworld.com.hk/en/node/157)

Answer (score 0):

If you had a version of  font that you wanted and legally could use, you can do (since iOS version 3.2):

Add the font file to the project in Xcode (in Resources for example).
Add the key UIAppFonts to the info.plist file and make it an array type.
Add the font file name to the array.
Use it by doing, for example, [UIFont fontWithName:@"fontnamr" size:20].