# NavigationItem Title Custom Font

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Is it legal (or okay with Apple) to have the title of a navigation bar or a navigation item have a custom font?

EDIT:

`titleView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Tahoma" size:20.0];` is not working with me.

Comment: Did you actually embed the font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure! There are many apps having those. The only thing they still may reject your app for is if your font isn't readable, or when it infriges someones copyright or something ...

Comment: Why isn't `titleView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Tahoma" size:20.0];` working then?

Also, I have a custom font, how can I install it?

Comment: Said that Apple doesn't reject apps using a custom font, they don't really support it either ... You probably need to read this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application