# iOS Custom Fonts

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uifont

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)

I am creating a label and I need it to use a custom font, or Tahoma. I installed the custom font on my Mac and in IB, when I edit the UILabel and choose that custom font, the text's font changes but as soon as I hit enter or finish changes, the font goes back to its default font.

On the other hand, Tahoma doesn't change at all.

I came cross this [article](http://bluecrowbar.com/blog/2010/12/ios-fonts.html) that shows the default iOS fonts. Tahoma is not listed. Is not possible to install a custom font in my app to use?

If so, how?

Comment: why do you need Tahoma? Helvetica is very close.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate: [Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)

Use the UIAppFonts key in the `Info.plist` file.

Comment: I did that - did not work. Tried assigning it to a label on a navigation bar..