# UITextField font style not changing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, input, textfield

I have the following problem - I want to change the UITextField font to a custom one. I am using this line of code:

```
textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"fontname.ttf" size:20];
```

I want to use this font:
[Neurm.ttf](http://photoshop.cc/id/neurm-ttf.html)
Can you please tell me what is wrong or just try it out and tell me is it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible you may have not gone through some necessary steps to embed a custom font in your app.

Check;

- [iOS Custom Fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233056/ios-custom-fonts)
- [Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)

and see if you missed anything.

Comment: Nope, I am doing everything right. I tried the way you told me but still no result. I think its because of the specific font, can you please try it and tell me what is the result?

Comment: Did you try setting 'NeuropolMedium' as the font name? i.e. [UIFont fontWithName:@"NeuropolMedium" size:20]

Answer (score 14):

You doing wrong Because no need to set extension (fontname.ttf) in your string.

```
textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"NEURM TTF" size:20];
```

and check following links how to use custom font in ios.

1.[How to use custom font in iOS Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351264/how-to-use-custom-font-in-ios-apps)

2.[iPhone Development: how to use custom fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462852/iphone-development-how-to-use-custom-fonts)

Comment: Nope, I am doing everything right. I tried the way you told me but still no result. I think its because of this font, can you please try it and tell me what is the result?

Comment: see my this answer may be it will be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581191/set-own-custom-colors-and-fonts-in-uicolor

Comment: any example for swift

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/)

```
someTf.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AlexBrush-Regular" size:20];
```

This is working correctly no need to give .ttf ext